# How to Stop a Service in Android when the application is not running.

Tags: android

I have Started my service in one of my main activity class.The problem is that when my application is not running I want to Stop my service.How can i implement this.Is there any option to stop it without stopping it using any button click or other click events of the control.

Also is there any way to indicate the service is running or not while my application is running

Comment: Than you Michael for your revision.

Answer (score 10):

Simply by firing an Intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Your_service.class);
```

Just add this block of code where you have stop your service:

```
stopService(intent);
```

**`Update:`**

add this method to each and every activity of your application

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int key, KeyEvent event)
{
  switch(key.getAction())
  {
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME :
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, Your_service.class);
         stopService(intent);
         break;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Actually i dont know at which point i have to stop it.beacuse I will end my appliction by navigating it from 1-3 pages or5-6 pages.So i cant predict when i will close my appliction

Comment: okay so give a item of option menu for stoping the service and place the above block of code inside that item and if answer helped you so please upvote it so that others can also get help from it.

Comment: Option menu means?where to place that?

Comment: Look options menu is collection of items which can be treated as button and it appears on the application screen when we press menu button of phone/emulator. Take a look on this it might solve your problem --> http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/options-menu-in-android-code.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.But My question is that i cant implement it in any of the click event of the control.Suppose I have navigate in my appplication from 1-3 pages.Then i clicked the home button of the device menu.At that point My application is not running Is it right?If so I need to Stop my Service .But now i find it get runnin?This is the actual problem.

Comment: okay so handle the event look when you will press the home button then a event will happen so there is a method named onKeyDown(int key, KeyEvent event). Okay let me edit my answer it will give you a better idea.

Answer (score 4):

Using intent you can stop the service.

```
Intent intentStartervice = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
stopService(intentStartService);
```

or

just pass the Context.

```
context.stopService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start service in onCreate of your launcher activity and stop service in onStop of the same activity. 
You can refer to this for complete service tutorial:

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

And yes,better you use the same intent variable to start and stop activity.At last,Don't forget to add your service to manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Activity manager on the adb shell:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity services [text search]
```

Replace `[text search]` with some text of your service to look for. You should get a "service record" with the following qualified name for the service:

/<fully.qualified.serviceclass>

Then stop it as so:

```
adb shell am stop-service <package name>/<fully.qualified.serviceclass>
```

Note that the service must have `exported=true` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, otherwise you'll get an

> Error stopping service

When running this.